# get instance id for rhel ec2 image in aws

Tags: rhel, aws, amazon-ec2

What syntax needs to be used in the following command in the terminal of a RHEL 8 AWS EC2 instance to return only the valid instance id instead of the corrupted value it is currently returning?

```
$ myinstid=$(curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id)
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    19  100    19    0     0   9500      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  9500
$ $myinstid
-bash: i-0u7t5y86blahblah: command not found
```

The value we want returned for `$myinstid` is `i-0u7t5y86blahblah` and NOT `-bash: i-0u7t5y86blahblah: command not found`.

Answer (score 2):

You should echo the variable to output its value. `echo "$myinstid"`

You are setting the value of `myinstid` to the output of the command `curl http://169.254.169.254/latest/meta-data/instance-id`. The output of the command in your case appears to be `i-0u7t5y86blahblah`. Then you are asking bash to run the variable `myinstid` in the shell, which for all intents and purposes here is the same thing as trying to run `i-0u7t5y86blahblah` as a command. This is why you are receiving the bash error `i-0u7t5y86blahblah: command not found`.